# I have a form I am putting together in PHP that displays nothing. Can anyone diagnose?

Tags: php, html, forms

It seems that the code I wrote has a major error that makes my page display blank. I am a noob to PHP, and it seems that something I am doing is incorrect. Could somebody spot what is wrong and possibly explain how I can identify this error in the future?

Also, before the comments come on it, I am aware that GET is a bad thing to use here, the final code will use POST, but it is this way for my debugging.

```
<?php
{

if(!preg_match( "^(?=[^\s]*?[0-9])(?=[^\s]*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" , $_GET['username']))
{
    echo username correct
}

if($_GET['password'] == $_GET['passwordc'])
{   
if(!preg_match( "^(?=[^\s]*?[0-9])(?=[^\s]*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" , $_GET['password']))
        {
        echo password correct; 
        }
}

if(!preg_match( "^[a-zA-Z]{1,}$" , $_GET['fName']))
{
    echo First Name correct;
}

if(!preg_match( "^[a-zA-Z]{1,}$" , $_GET['lName']))
{
    echo Last Name correct;
}

if(!preg_match( "^\d{1,2}$" , $_GET['age']))
{
    echo age correct;
}

if(!preg_match( "^(m|M|f|F)$" , $_GET['gender']))
{
    echo Gender correct;
}

if(!preg_match( "^(((0[13578]|(10|12))/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))|(02/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]))|((0[469]|11)/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)))/[0-9]{4}$" , $_GET['birthday']))
{    
    echo Birthday correct;
}

if(!preg_match( "^\d{4}$" , $_GET['year']))
{
    echo Graduation year correct;
}


}
?>
<html>



<form method="GET" action="">
    Enter Username: <input name="username" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Password: <input name="password" type="password" />
    <br>
    Confirm Password: <input name="passwordc" type="password" />
    <br>
    <br>
    Personal Info:
    <br>
    Enter First Name: <input name="fName" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Last Name: <input name="lName" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Age:<input name="age" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Gender (m/f):<input name="gender" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Birthday (mm/dd/yyyy):<input name="birthday" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Graduation Year:<input name="year" type="text" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value = "Submit!" />
</form>


</html>
```

Comment: white page of death, error reporting\display are off, turn them on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Single quotes and slash delimiters for regular expressions, please. Also, short, self-contained code examples, please.

Comment: in addition i don't like any of your checks, let me decide what my name\password  is. many valid names would fail your check

Comment: Also in addition, quote your strings. Also also, always use strict equality, because if my password is only numbers, that check just doesn’t work. Also also also, use a dropdown for gender if you have two valid options. Or just allow free entry for gender. And use some labels, and more CSS and less `<br>`. `<input type="date">`. Don’t attempt to enforce password patterns. Consider Unicode. Use `+` instead of `{1,}`.

Comment: Lots of parse errors.

Comment: What they said, plus, don't use `$_GET` when sending sensitive information, such as passwords.

Comment: (Rather, don’t use GET to perform actions. Use GET to get things and POST to do things, in general.)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {

if(!preg_match( '/^(?=[^\s]*?[0-9])(?=[^\s]*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/' , $_GET['username']))
{
    echo "username correct";
}

if($_GET['password'] == $_GET['passwordc'])
{   
if(!preg_match( '/^(?=[^\s]*?[0-9])(?=[^\s]*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/' , $_GET['password']))
        {
        echo "password correct"; 
        }
}

if(!preg_match( '/^[a-zA-Z]{1,}$/' , $_GET['fName']))
{
    echo "First Name correct";
}

if(!preg_match( '/^[a-zA-Z]{1,}$/' , $_GET['lName']))
{
    echo "Last Name correct";
}

if(!preg_match( '/^\d{1,2}$/' , $_GET['age']))
{
    echo "age correct";
}

if(!preg_match( '/^(m|M|f|F)$/' , $_GET['gender']))
{
    echo "Gender correct";
}

if(!preg_match( '/^(((0[13578]|(10|12))/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))|(02/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]))|((0[469]|11)/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)))/[0-9]{4}$/' , $_GET['birthday']))
{    
    echo "Birthday correct";
}

if(!preg_match( '/^\d{4}$/' , $_GET['year']))
{
    echo "Graduation year correct";
}

}
?>
<html>



<form method="GET" action="">
    Enter Username: <input name="username" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Password: <input name="password" type="password" />
    <br>
    Confirm Password: <input name="passwordc" type="password" />
    <br>
    <br>
    Personal Info:
    <br>
    Enter First Name: <input name="fName" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Last Name: <input name="lName" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Age:<input name="age" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Gender (m/f):<input name="gender" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Birthday (mm/dd/yyyy):<input name="birthday" type="text" />
    <br>
    Enter Graduation Year:<input name="year" type="text" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value = "Submit!" />
</form>


</html>
```

I also added a check for submit. The form loads, I didn't test beyond that.

Comment: It won’t, because there are still no delimiters on the regular expressions.

Comment: I delimited the expressions